# Unable to instantiate class nltk.classify.textcat.TextCat

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I'm trying to run the following:

```
import nltk 
tc = nltk.classify.textcat.TextCat()
```

I get the following error:

```
OSError: classify.textcat requires the regex module that supports unicode. Try '$ pip install regex' and see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex for further details.
```

I've tried adding `import regex`  before `import nltk` but unfortunately I still get the same error.
What have I missed?

Comment: Did you `pip install regex` like the error suggests?

Comment: Yes, and when I run `import regex` alone I don't get any error

Comment: I ran exactly the same command on python=3.6, nltk==3.5 and re==2.2.1. Worked for me. Check after updating your regex to latest version

Comment: Mine is:
Python=3.6.4, nltk=3.2.5 ,regex=2.5.83 .
Wierd it shows I have an old version of nltk, I've installed it today

Comment: @Itai - do you have multiple python installations on your computer? it could be that you installed into a different environment by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sagar Dawda and @jakub for their generous help.
What resolved this was updating nltk version from 3.2.5 to 3.5